# Display reference of order summary in mysql using prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, payment, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem with my module. I created a `payment module` based on `bankwire module` with some differences. Below is the issue,

I need to create a form in `payment_execution.tpl` with fields that come from database (like address firstname, lastname, etc.). I managed to get those information's from database, but now *`I need to get the reference of the order`* (I can't get it from the database of course because it's not stored there yet, or at least I can't found it).

My question is, how can I get the order reference, so I could insert it in the form I created in `payment_execution.tpl`?

Thank you.
Regards

Comment: The order is not created yet, so there's no order reference. You can store the cart reference witch is later linked to the order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it that the reference is not stored yet. but is there a way to "call" the generated reference in my tpl file so I can forwrd it in a form? I have to forward it to make payment.

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot get the "reference" as in the term that PS uses for saying "order number", you actually **can** get the **ID** of the next order in Prestashop.
Since the standard PS "reference" is randomly generated you will not be able to use this to get the actual "reference" if that is what you need. I'm sure you can use the order id to achieve what you want though...

Use `Order::getNextOrderId()` (line 1604 in Order.php Class) to retrieve it.

Lots of payment modules (especially ones for external payment services) use this function since it is often required for validation and bookkeeping.